# Mac screen reader only reading html tags not the contents

Tags: macos, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

Before starting, this might be a silly setting changes required for Mac Voice over which I has to be do in order to fix this, but I am totally stuck with this issue.

Whenever I start screen reader on Mac ( by loading my webpage on the browser - chrome ), it starts reading only the HTML tags not the content appearing on the DOM.

For eg. the moment I start screen reader, it starts reading ( " `<div aria-role=".." ... > ... </div> ...`  ")

Does anyone knows any setting changes has to be done to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe try using Safari...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working for chrome by changing the settings in to `VoiceOver Utility` => `Web` tab => uncheck `Enable Live Region`.

Answer (score 0):

VoiceOver behaves differently for Chrome, FF, and Safari. And since VO only has Read/Browse mode, it sounds like it's not finding any landmarks within your code. Check your code for any semantic issues. Also, you can validate your markup using a browser plugin like Deque's AXE. It's what I prefer when I need to do a quick accessibility audit. VO also uses different key combinations like "VO-Shift-Down Arrow" instead of native keyboard function to perform tasks we would think should be simple but they're anything but. It's possible, you'll need to modify/enable the key combo that enables you to read the content.